# Setting .outerHTML clears all .innerHTML element contents

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<tr id="row1" data-Source="{{row_id}}">
    <td><input id="chk1" class="chk" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input id="chk2" class="chk" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input id="chk3" class="chk" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
(() => {
    
    
    document.getElementById("chk1").checked = true;
    
    let insertTR = document.getElementById("row1").cloneNode(true);
    
    let elems = insertTR.querySelectorAll(".chk");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].checked = true;
    }

    
    document.getElementById("theTable").appendChild(insertTR);
    
})()
```

The JS spec says that I cannot access an element's .outerHTML while it is not attached to the DOM body, and in fact, I get an error in the attempt to set the .outerHTML.

So:

```
document.getElementById("theTable").appendChild(insertTR);

insertTR.outerHTML = insertTR.outerHTML.replace("{{row_id}}","myRowId");
```

That works fine to take care of the TR's `{{row_id}}` tag, but now, my previously checked checkbox is now **unchecked**.

Mozilla docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) say:

*"Setting the value of outerHTML replaces the element and all of its descendants with a new DOM tree constructed by parsing the specified htmlString."*

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do all of this? Seems like a potential [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: I had to read that xy problem link to see what you meant.  Must admit, that's a pretty insightful observation.  However, the code I have here is condensed for readability.  What I am doing is constructing a table from a template inside a loop that is merging it with json data.  That's the X part that might be what you are referring to.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but that's still not too clear. What template, loop and JSON data are you talking about? `data-Source="{{row_source}}"` seems like a strange way to solve a problem. There's almost definitely a better way. For starters, if you have to use templates, I'd suggest using EJS. But I'm not sure you'll even need that; it's a pretty strange thing to be using on the client side in general. The point of this exercise is to steer you away from complex hacks you don't even need, when there's an elegant and direct solution that could be suggested if you'd provide full context.

Comment: Hopefully, I have enough room here to explain.  Every element on the page that has a "data-field" class has an evenListener that sets a "dirty" status on the page when it's value changes.  Later, when they press a "save" button, all those dirty elements are gathered into JSON to submit to the server.  The JSON has to contain the sql table, key field name, and key_field value.  These can be on any level of container all the way down to the field.  Most often in the container div.  But on row data, every row has a unique key.  I put that in each row as an attribute so ".closest()" will find it.

Comment: Sorry, for that, but I only have so much space in a comment.  ;-)

I eventually solved it by avoiding reaching out to outerHTML at all, and instead `insertTR.setAttribute("row_source","myRowId");`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string of the HTML before you make it into an element and append it. –

```js
function elemFromString(html) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("div");
  dummy.innerHTML = html.trim();
  if (dummy.children.length > 1) {
    console.error("expecting one wrapping element for html. will return only firstChild")
  }
  var result = dummy.firstChild;
  result.parentNode.removeChild(result)
  return result;
}


(() => {
  document.getElementById("chk1").checked = true;
  let insertTR_html = document.getElementById("row1").outerHTML;
  insertTR_html = insertTR_html.replace("this", "that");
  let insertTR = elemFromString(insertTR_html);
  let elems = insertTR.querySelectorAll(".chk");
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].checked = true;
  }
  document.getElementById("theTable").appendChild(insertTR);
})()
```

Comment: This may not be relevant so forgive me if not but just encase, I noticed that if you change

insertTR.outerHTML = insertTR.outerHTML.replace('{{row_source}}','SQLTableName');" 


to simply be:  

insertTR.outerHTML.replace('{{row_source}}','SQLTableName');   

removing the

"insertTR.outerHTML =" 

part it appears to work:  https://jsfiddle.net/esc6bpgj/

Comment: Wow, that's a "think outside the box" answer.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided on this approach instead:

```
let insertTR = document.getElementById("row1").cloneNode(true);

insertTR.setAttribute("data-Source","myRowId")
```

Setting the attribute through `.setAttribute()` instead of attempting to manipulate it's `.outerHTML`.

Works fine now.